# Select with 2 tables

Tags: sql, select

I read past questions but I couldn't solve my issue :(

This is my case.

```
>>table paciente
idPaciente | nombres | apellidos | fecNac | direccion | telefono | idenfermedad | idApoderado

>>table enfermedad
idenfermedad | detalle

>>table apoderado
idApoderado | nameA | apeA
```

I wanted to have this as a result:

```
idPaciente | nombres | apellidos | fecNac | direccion | telefono | detalle | nameA | apeA
```

Comment: Ok, show us what you've got. Have you written any code already?

Comment: Is there something a couple of joins didn't do for you?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - I was thinking the same thing, but it so simple, I just did it anyway...

Comment: Hey guys thanks for answer ! I've got this code: 

`SELECT p.nombres, p.apellidos, e.detalle FROM paciente p LEFT JOIN enfermedad e ON p.idenfermedad = e.idenfermedad;`

what's the difference using left join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT p.idPaciente, p.nombres, p.apellidos, p.fecNac, p.direccion, p.telefono, 
       e.detalle, a.nameA, a.apeA
FROM paciente as p
JOIN enfermedad as e on e.idenfermedad = p.idenfermedad 
JOIN apoderado as a on e.idApoderado = a.idApoderado
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JOIN clauses using the primary key of the foreign key table(s) from your primary table, where those foreign keys exist.  Also note the use of table aliases (i.e. paciente p), it helps cut down on typing :)

```
select 
  p.idPaciente, 
  p.nombres,
  p.apellidos, 
  p.fecNac, 
  p.direccion, 
  p.telefono, 
  e.detalle, 
  a.nameA,
  a.apeA 

from paciente p
join enfermedad e on e.idApoderado = p.idApoderado 
join apoderado a on a.idPaciente = p.idPaciente
```

And try playing around with LEFT and RIGHT joins to see the different resultsets.

```
select 
  p.idPaciente, 
  p.nombres,
  p.apellidos, 
  p.fecNac, 
  p.direccion, 
  p.telefono, 
  e.detalle, 
  a.nameA,
  a.apeA 

from paciente p
left join enfermedad e on e.idApoderado = p.idApoderado 
left join apoderado a on a.idPaciente = p.idPaciente
```

Comment: what's the difference using LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: The LEFT JOIN will return ALL rows from the LEFT table and fill the RIGHT table columns (resultset) with NULLS where a match could not be found in the RIGHT table.